# How do I know if it is an actual Dedicated server?

Tags: dedicated-server

I am looking at this offer & I cannot understand whether it is an actual dedicated server (as in dedicated "hardware" server).

http://www.ovh.co.uk/products/eg_ssd.xml

I am worried, because under Processor it says:

```
Virtualisation: VT Instructions
Turbo Boost Technology @ 2.93GHz
```

Do I get my own kernel?

Answer (score 9):

VT is just a processor technology, it doesn't necessarily mean that your server is virtualized. That being said, you should just call and ask them rather than asking us to guess whether what a specific provider does.

Answer (score 1):

That represents the type of virtualization technology used by the processor and doesn't mean that your machine is run in a virtualized environment. Both the turbo boost and VT technology stacks are covered on the IBM page linked off of the page linked:

http://www.intel.com/technology/virtualization/ 
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html

Now: as far as being able to tell if your OS is running inside of a VM, it can certainly be done through direct or inferred hardware fingerprinting; what you would not be able to detect using any method I'm aware of, is the number of running domains on an Oracle/SUN piece of hardware in an attempt to see if that physical box is shared out (outside of the XSCF interface).

Best bet .... ask your hosting provider and check your SLA.

Comment: No, it doesn't indicate what hypervisor is used.  Also, you cannot ever detect, for certain, whether you're running virtualised.  Anything you can detect can be spoofed.

Comment: thanks, got left in while i was doing other edits ... removed for accuracy - was going to discuss type 1 and 2 hypervisors/detections as part of the answer.